# MySQL View data type issue?

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures, view, mariadb

I thought columns in a `VIEW` simply inherited data types used in the underlying `TABLE`, but that doesn't seem to be true.

I have a MySQL `TABLE` like:

### "`myTable`"

**`FIELD   TYPE                  NULL  KEY  DEFAULT  EXTRA`**           
`id      int(11)               NO    PRI  NULL     auto_increment`  
`dt      datetime              NO    MUL  NULL`                     
`foo     smallint(5) unsigned  NO         NULL`

I can **query** the table like:
`SELECT dt, SUM(foo) FROM myTable WHERE dt>DATE_SUB(Now(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) GROUP BY dt`

---

Now I need the ability to query the same data but using alternate names for some columns (such as "`foo`").
[I'll skip the long explanation of *why*!]

I figured a simple solution was a `VIEW`:
`CREATE VIEW myView AS ( SELECT id, dt, grps AS groups FROM myTable ORDER BY dt )`

This creates a view with columns like:

### "`myView`"

**`FIELD   TYPE                  NULL  KEY  DEFAULT  EXTRA`**           
`id      int(11)               NO         0`                        
`dt      datetime              NO         NULL`                     
`foobar  smallint(5) unsigned  NO         NULL`

---

**The problem** arises when I **query** the view: (almost identical to the previous query)

`SELECT dt, SUM(foobar) AS foo FROM myView WHERE dt>DATE_SUB(Now(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) GROUP BY dt`

The query runs without producing an error but the response is **zero records**.

I discovered that if I `CAST` the `WHERE` clause like this, then it works properly (although it's painfully slow.)

. . . `WHERE CAST(dt>DATE_SUB(Now(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)`

`CAST`ing all columns would be tedious, plus it's slowing down query execution quite a bit. (There are 5 million records and growing.)

Why is sql forcing me to re-cast the fields?  What can I do about it?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all remove `ORDER BY dt` from the view's creation text. Most probably it makes slow down in the next step.

Comment: Removing the `ORDER BY` from the view definition does indeed help. 

I still consider the empty result set a bug though, and will create a bug report for that ...

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan - That fixed it!  Thanks - but... Huh?!  Why would ordering the underlying records (by date) cause no records to be returned when grouping (by date)?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan - if you'd like to change that to an answer (with explanation if possible?!) then I'll accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is a regression somehow introduced with MariaDB 10.2. Somehow having an `ORDER BY` in the view definition does not turn out well with a `GROUP BY` on the same column on queries using that view.

I created the following bug report for this:

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-23826

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `ORDER BY` clause within the creation statement of the view.

Since, for every call of the view the scanning and the sorting occur for the whole record set before bringing the result for which you might not want to sort the result. This makes `ORDER BY` clause redundant, and might probably cause adverse impact on performance.